# How to generate string by joining ArrayList of Strings in spel?

Tags: java, spring, string, concatenation, spring-el

I want to form a new string from ArrayList of Strings with a particular delimiter using spel.

```
list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want to make a String s = "a,b,c" from above list.

I tried many expressions such as `StringUtils.join(list, ',')`, `list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(','))`, etc.
but every time I'm getting an error

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'StringUtils' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Is there any way to do this in spel?

Answer (score 0):

If `StringUtils.join` is a static method, you need `T(com.my.StringUtils).join(...)` (need full class name too).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer, or at least, worked for me in spinnaker's SpEL:

```
${ T(String).join(',', "a", "b" ,"c" )  }
"a,b,c"
```

and even better, for my particular use case, to get rid of nasty nulls:

```
${ T(String).join(',', ({"a", null ,"c"}.?[#this != null]) ) }
"a,c"
```

and it even worked for:

```
${ T(String).join(' / ', someList )}
${ T(String).join(' / ', someSimpleMap.values() )}
```

(by "simple map", I mean, single depth, set of `A: B`, no nested or otherwise complex maps.  Left that adventure to the reader :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use this instead

```
String lst[] = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
System.out.println(String.join(",",lst)); //here output will be a,b,c
```

Comment: Sorry but OP was asking for a solution in SpEL (Spring Expression Language), not in plain Java